# How do i make this image appear in front of this other as an object?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

i'm trying to convert a normal javascript game code to react but i'm finding a lot of problems that i don't know how to solve (i'm not good with web development so, sorry if i misspell something)

what i want is that an image become 100% adjusted to the viewport and another image, which is a game character, stay in front of it, but the css styles aren't applying to them

this is my javascript code and my css:

```
import './App.css';
import Spring from './components/Spring'
import Background from './components/Background';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="game">
      <Background className="fundo"></Background>
      <Spring classname='Spring'></Spring>
      <div className='message'>Press enter to start</div>
      <div class="score">
        <span class="score_title"></span>
        <span class="score_val"></span>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and this is my css for now:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.game {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}

.Spring {
  height: 100px;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 30vw;
  z-index: 100;
}

.fundo{
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  z-index: 99;
}

.pipe_sprite {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40vh;
  left: 100vw;
  height: 70vh;
  width: 6vw;
  background-color: green;
}

.message {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 10vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: black;
  top: 12vh;
  left: 20vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.score {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  height: 10vh;
  font-size: 10vh;
  font-weight: 100;
  color: goldenrod;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.score_val {
  color: gold;
}
```

if anyone want to see my react components that i'm trying to apply the style, there it is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import background from './sprites/red_sun_ultimate.gif'

class Background extends Component {
    state = {  } 
    render() { 
        return <img src={background} alt='Background'></img>;
    }
}
 
export default Background;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import springSprite from './sprites/Spring_2.0.gif'

class Spring extends Component {
    state = {  } 
    render() { 
        return <img src={springSprite} alt='Spring'></img>;
    }
}
 
export default Spring;
```

i really don't know what to do by this point, my styles are applying to the score val and etc but i just can't figure out why the styles aren't applying to the other things too

the result i'm getting is:

[this is what i'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/heRQS.png)

Comment: in Spring tag you are using classname try to use className

Comment: @Nisha i did it but still nothing happened

Comment: go to your page and  inspect your character /spring class and see is it showing on the page?

Comment: @Nisha is showing the same of the image that i put in this question